# Organize Many Views

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

I have to create a layout like this:

[image: Screen Shot]

As you can see, all views (images, buttons) are in a scrollable screen. It is a layout for an album.

The issue is when I show this album screen with many images, it crashes with an out of memory error.

The way I choose is to put all of them in a `LinearLayout` inside a `ScrollView`. I know if we need to show many view we can use listview, but I can not organize all of these views with a `ListView`.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Are you using bitmap to display image? Many times we are facing OutOfMemory issue because of bitmaps

Comment: if you have error than so your code where you set imagebitmap...

Comment: @AkbariDipali correct, i working with many bitmap.
 to:
altaf my app work ok if image around 20, but laggy and crash after switch some screen or number of image get bigger

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1. Organize the items such that each item view in the `ListView` has a group of staggered elements eventually they can be blocked out into `ListView` elements.  Every N images the tops/bottoms would have to line up at the view boundary.  You can perhaps place 4-6 images in the staggered pattern such that the effect is still achieved, but that block of elements becomes a view that can be recycled.
2. Use two `ListView` elements side-by side.  You can pass an `OnScrollListener` to each `ListView` to synchronize their scrolling movements regardless of which one is touched, giving the appearance that it is one view.  In this way you can fully stagger the images, but the adapter is a bit more work since you have to serve two views from one data source.

Answer (score 0):

For making this type of view you have to use linear layout . 
like here

linear layout (vertical)
title 
image
linear layout horizontal 
{
linear layout vertical 
button button 
image 
image
...
}
linear layout vertical
{
image
image 
...
}

Answer (score 0):

you can use inSampleSize to reduce memory occupied.

Here is my code

```
public static Bitmap decodeAndResizeFile(File f) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here, it will decode image using `inSampleSize` and this code will find the best `inSampleSize` values for you.

It worked Fine for me.

if you don't want to use above code, You can also use `bitmap.recycle()` and `System.gc()` to release unused memory.But, above one works fine for me. You can use either of the two.

```
objbitmap.recycle();
objbitmap = null;
System.gc();
```

Hope, this may solve the issue!